# When stacking LSTM's, should the hidden units increase?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, hyperparameter-optimization

I'm using Weights and Biases to do some hyperparameter sweeping for a supervised sequence-to-sequence problem I'm working on. One thing I noticed is that the sweeps with a gradually increasing number of hidden units tend to have a lower validation loss:

[image]

I'm wondering if this is generally true or just a function of my particular problem?